# Where to find more info on Visual Studio 2010 package development?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vspackage

I'm trying to find in depth guide on vs package development.

I've tried with a few books (Visual Studio 2010 Package Development by Istvan Novak, [http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Visual-Studio-Extensibility-Nayyeri/dp/0470230843/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1314871900&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470230843)).

Im interested in VS architecture, services, and internal components useful for Package development.

Does anyone know about more resources for this, books, sites, documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DiveDeeper's blog](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/tags/VSX/default.aspx) has a very good set of articles too.

I guess a book was to be published on VS Package development (by Aug 2010), I cannot find it in Amazon however.

DiveDeeper has listed all his articles on [codeplex](http://learnvsxnow.codeplex.com) now.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [mztools](http://www.mztools.com/resources_vsnet_addins.aspx) site to be very useful, an accumulation of many articles and examples.